# Properties of a certain matrix in a certain field

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, matrices, graph-theory

> Let $\mathbb{F}$ be a field on two elements, $0$ and $1$ and $G = (V,E)$ be a graph. Let $S$ be a $|V|\times |E|$ matrix in $F$ whose $(i,j)$ entry is $1$ if edge $j$ is incident with vertex $i$ and $0$ otherwise. Determine, with proof, which vectors are in the null space of $S$ in the field $\mathbb{F}$ and which vectors are in the row space of $S$ in terms of $G$.

By definition, the right null space of $S$ is the set of vectors $x\in \mathbb{F}^{|E|}$ so that $S x = 0.$ Each column of $S$ contains $2$ nonzero entries, since each edge is connected to $2$ vertices. In order for $Sx = 0,$ we need each vertex of $G$ to be incident with an even number of edges corresponding to entries of $x$ ($0$ if the edges are included and $1$ otherwise). But I'm not sure what the set of these vectors represents in terms of $G$.

As for the row space, by definition, the row space is the set of vectors in $\mathbb{F}^{|E|}$ of the form $S^T x$ for some $x\in \mathbb{F}^{|V|}.$ The rows of $S^T$ each have exactly two $1$'s and the rest of the entries are $0$. So if row $e$ of $S^T$ is incident with two vertices $v_1$ and $v_2$ corresponding to entries of $x$, then the $e$th entry of $S^T x$ will be $0.$ Similarly, if row $e$ of $S^T$ is incident with no vertices corresponding to entries of $x$, then the $e$th entry of $S^T x$ will be $0.$ Only when row $e$ of $S^T$ is incident with exactly one vertex corresponding to an entry of $x$ will the $e$th entry of $S^T x$ be $1$. But again I'm not sure what these vectors $S^T x$ represent in terms of $G$.

Comment: I saw that you shot down someone suggesting Bondy and Murty by saying that you don't understand it. It seems to suggest you might want to consider studying that book for precisely that reason. (make sure you find the undergraduate book of theirs and not the graduate text)

Comment: tbh, maybe Bondy's Textbook isn't that difficult. For some reason, I've been having trouble understanding some rather simple graph theory problems lately (e.g. menger's theorem, which also tends to appear quite often in introductory textbooks such as [this one](https://www.whitman.edu/mathematics/cgt_online/cgt.pdf)). I'm using [this springer textbook](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4471-6569-9#about) btw.

Comment: The row space of $S$ is the column space of $S^T$: with the definition of $S$ you gave at the bottom, each row of $S$ should is indexed by a vertex $v$ and has $|E|$ entries. Why are you discussing the rows of $S^T$?

Comment: @Joppy I'm discussing the rows of $S^T$ because each element in the row space is of the form $S^T x$ for some $x.$

Comment: @MorganRodgers apologies for deleting that question where you posted a proof based on a proof from Bondy and Murty. I'm currently trying to limit the number of questions that show up in my profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the product $Sx$, $x\in\mathbf{F}_2^{\lvert E\rvert}$, the vector $x$ corresponds to a set of edges of $G$. As you've observed, $Sx=0$ means that every vertex of $G$ is incident on an even number of edges of the edge set represented by $x$. The set of edges of a cycle of $G$ has this property. More generally, the set of edges of tour of $G$ has this property. (In a tour, vertices may be visited multiple times, but edges are used only once.) More generally still, the set of edges of a disjoint union of tours has this property. Such disjoint unions are equivalent to edge sets of even-degree subgraphs, or, in other words, subgraphs in which every connected component has an Euler tour.

With regard to the row space of $S$: in the product $x^TS$, $x\in\mathbf{F}_2^{\lvert V\rvert}$, the vector $x$ represents a set of vertices of $G$. The elements of the vector $x^TS$ correspond to edges. As you have found, an element of $x^TS$ equals $0$ when either both vertices on the corresponding edge are in the vertex set corresponding to $x$ or neither vertex is in that set; an element of $x^TS$ equals $1$ when exactly one of the vertices on the corresponding edge is in the vertex set corresponding to $x$. Hence the vector $x^TS$ represents the set of edges that join a vertex in the set corresponding to $x$ to a vertex not in that set. There is an induced subgraph corresponding to $x$, and $x^TS$ can be thought of as the set of external edges—edges connecting to vertices outside the induced subgraph.

The correspondence between row-space vectors and sets of external edges of induced subgraphs is not one-to-one for the following reasons: (1) if $X$ is the sets of vertices corresponding to $x$, the the subgraph induced by $X$ has the same external edge set as the subgraph induced by $V\setminus X$; (2) if $G$ is not connected then any connected component or union of connected components has no external edges, just as the empty subgraph does. In other words, if $y_1$, $y_2$, ..., $y_m$ are vectors corresponding to vertex sets of connected components, then $y_j^TS=0$ for all $j\in\{1,2,\ldots,m\}$ and
$$
(x^T+y_1^T+\ldots+y_m^T)S=x^TS
$$
for any $x\in\mathbf{F}_2^{\lvert V\rvert}$.

So there is a one-to-one correspondence between vectors in the row space of $S$ and equivalence classes of partitions of the vertex set of $G$ into two parts, where the partition $\{X,Y\}$ is the same partition as $\{Y,X\}$. The notion of equivalence being used here is the following: let $V$ be partitioned as $\{X,Y,C\}$ where $C$ is the set of vertices of a connected component of $G$. Then $\{X\cup C,Y\}\sim\{X,Y\cup C\}$.

Comment: So is it incorrect to say that that the row space is the empty set and the set of edges for which the corresponding induced subgraph has at least one vertex of odd degree?

Comment: The edge sets you describe do not include everything. (The fact that the empty set is different from the rest should arouse suspicion that other edge sets are missing.) Consider the graph $C_4$, with vertices labeled $1$, $2$, $3$, $4$ in clockwise order. The vertex set $X=\{1,3\}$ has all four edges as external edges, and indeed $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 & 1 & 1\end{bmatrix}$ is in the row space. But if I'm understanding what you mean by $G[E]$ correctly, the corresponding induced subgraph has no vertices of odd degree.

Comment: thanks. so $(1,1,1,1)$ in your example is in both the row space and null space, right? But aren't the row space and null space orthogonal? Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Also, if I'm understanding your solution correctly, would it be correct to say the elements of the row space are cuts induced by subgraphs $S$ in $G$ (a cut induced by a subgraph $S$ of $G$ is a set of edges with exactly one end in $S$)?

Comment: One thing that takes some getting used to when doing linear algebra over finite fields is that vectors can be self-orthogonal. So $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 & 1 & 1\end{bmatrix}\cdot\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 & 1 & 1\end{bmatrix}=1+1+1+1=0$ in $\mathbf{F}_2$. As for your second question, I would say yes. Remember, however, that different vectors in the product $x^TS$ can correspond to the same cut: if the cut doesn't go through a particular connected component, that component may be placed on either side of the cut, giving different vectors $x$ but the same vector $x^TS$.